# my program for communication using socket.i am unable to type anything in cmd. it is not displaying anything even though i type

Tags: java, sockets, networking, client-server

i am creating a simple client server communication . but  i am unable to type anything in the command prompt. 
***code for server***

i am unable to type anything in cmd when i run program

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Tests
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
  try
  {
 ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(3000);
 Socket c = server.accept();
     DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(c.getOutputStream());
     DataInputStream in  = new DataInputStream(c.getInputStream());
     DataInputStream console = new DataInputStream(System.in);


     String input,output;
     while (true)
     {
            input = in.readLine();
        System.out.println("Client says: " + input);
    output = console.readLine();
    out.writeBytes(output+ '\n');
     }


  }
  catch(IOException e)
  { System.out.println("IO Error in streams " + e); }
}
}
```

***code for client***

please help me

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

  public class Testc
 {
   public static void main(String[] args)
 {

  try 
  {
     Socket client = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 3000);
     DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
     DataInputStream  in  = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
     DataInputStream console = new DataInputStream(System.in);
     System.out.println("Connected. Enter text:");

     String input,output;
     while (true) 
     {
       input = in.readLine();
       System.out.println("server says : "+ input);
   output = console.readLine();
       out.writeBytes(output + '\n');

     }


  } 
  catch (UnknownHostException e) 
  { System.err.println("error"); } 
  catch (IOException e) 
  { System.err.println("I/O error"); }
 }
 }
```

Comment: Both the client and the server are waiting for `in.readLine()`, this is a blocking call. So the server is waiting on input from the client and the client is waiting on input from the server; as they are both waiting for input neither can provide input. **Deadlock**. You need to write down, very carefully, who does what and in what order and then rewrite the code accordingly.

Comment: Translation: use Threads, and may the Many-Tentacled One eat you first.